# python: multiprocessing Event

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What is difference between `multiprocessing.Event` and `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Event`. When do I use each? Why two different objects exist?

Same question for other similar objects existing in `multiprocessing` directly and also in `Manager` (`Lock`, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only given answer is not very correct and others wasn't given.

I looked it up my own, and found that `multiprocessing.Event` can be used to synch between processes, it's completely alright.

`Event` and other objects from `multiprocessing.Manager` exist to be able to synchronize things between processes that runs on *different machines* via sockets under the hood. They also can be used synchronize on single machine, but less efficient for this than just using synch objects from `multiprocessing.synchronize` (like `Event` and `Lock` and others)

Comment: You can user Managers on the same machine, the idea is to provide proxies objects which can interracts with the real shared ressources published through the Manager. In a way it's a kind of "RPC-lite"

Comment: @utapyngo: in section "16.6.1.4. Sharing state between processes", doc of 2.7, especially read last part. And also some googling and reading tutorials

Answer (score 1):

multiprocessing.Manager is essentially a specialised process that will create instances of multiprocessing's synchronisation primitives on demand in its own address space, and let you access them through RPC proxies. The primitives behave the same, and they have the added flexibility of being accessible from remote hosts (using TCP in the remote case).